# how to make a db schema such that its use is supported by all db management systems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

is there a windows xp utility to make a database such that its support by sql server, oracle, and other db management systems.

the database schema is very huge so i would like to know what to use to  make it so its protable from sql server to oracle if future demands that change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend building your database using an **[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)** like Hibernate for Java (or NHibernate for .NET). This would allow you to seamlessly transition from [**one database type to the other**](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate) with little to no issues. They would allow you to logically create the database schema without a specific database in mind, which you could then move from one database to the other.

I have created applications which change from SQL Server to MySQL to Oracle to MS Access to SQLite easily (clients love that flexibility).

However, you would need to know your way around programming...

Answer (score 1):

In short, what you seek is nearly impossible to do successfully. Every database product has enough quirks that building such database would not perform well and would be too limiting in terms of the features you were able to use. I.e, you have to play the game of lowest common denominator with respect to features that all products implement you want to support. A far better solution is to abstract the data layer into its own library accessed via interfaces so that you can swap out your data layer. ORMs, as Rafael E. Belliard suggested, makes this simpler but it can also be done manually.

Comment: @user287745 - Manually, in that you write the methods that implement your data access interface(s) instead of having an ORM build those methods.